# I converted Type to shape, but now I want to make the entire vector one color

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, vector, text, typefaces

Is there any way I can flatten this small portion of the vector? To me it looks like a pixel that I should be able to paint, or change the color of. However, I tried to Edit > Recolor, and it did not work.

[image]

After further inspection, it looks like the lower right side pixel is a "Spot Color". How do I make all spot colors the exact same as the other colors?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The reason you see that odd color pixel is because you are in Pixel Preview mode (more info on that [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/best-practices-creating-web-graphics.html#main-pars_heading_1)).  Disable that view by unchecking View > Pixel Preview (⌥⌘+Y).

But to answer your question about changing the color, just in case anyone else finds this and wonders:

1. Select the type and convert it to outlines (⇧⌘+O)
2. (Optional) Select all the newly created paths you want to change to this color and combine into a compound path (⌘+8)
3. Change the compound path to the color you want

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. I had to release the clipping mask or something. After I created outlines from the type, it did not work. (illustrator didn't outline the type, and it didn't change color).